# Error: Assignment to expression with array type in named pipes

Tags: c, arrays

So apparently I am getting this error when I am trying to compile my client side of things. The client should read the text file line by line and send the variable to server side. The code is as follows:

```
 #define FIFONAME "my fifo"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

int fd;
char buffer[1024];
char const* const filename = argv[1] ;
FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
int i,j;
char array[128][128];
   char line [128];

/*Open the FIFO for writing. It was created by the server.
*/
if ((fd = open (FIFONAME, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    perror ("client : open");
    exit (1); }

for(i=0; i=128;i++)
for(j=0; j=128;j++)
arra[j]= '\0';

for (i=0; i<128; i++)
line = '\0';

if (file !=NULL)
{
    i=0;
    while (fgets(line,sizeof line, file) != NULL) 
    strcpy(arra, line);
    printf ("%s",&arra);
    i++;

}


while ((file = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) >0) {
write(fd, buffer, file);
}

fclose(file);
//close (fd);
return (0);
}
```

Is there anyway that this error can be solved?

Comment: `file = read(...` ??

Comment: "*I am getting this error*" the compiler tells you *exactly where*,  in which line it feels the error  is. This is helpful info. As well for us. You do not want us to guess, won't you?

Comment: Sorry about that, the error that they are giving is on the array[j]= '\0'; and line= '\0';

Comment: The code won't compile. You seems to have messed up your copypasta. Also the indention is ...well, at least sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
char line [128];
```

`line` is defined as an array of 128 `char`.

Here

```
for (i=0; i<128; i++)
  line = '\0';
```

the code tries 128 times to assign the character literal '\0' to the *whole* array. This does not make sense.

What you *might* want is setting all 128 elements of `line` to `'\0'`. So do this step by step:

```
for (i=0; i<128; i++)
  line[i] = '\0';
```